# jQuery button click to change display none to show wont work on form

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a form within a table and want to show half the form, once it is filled in the user can press a step 2 button to toggle the rest of the form underneath it in the same form and div.

I was trying to use a div id called hideform to change the display properties to none until a button was clicked

**HTML**

```
  <div id="form">
        <h1>Booking</h1>
        <p>Fill in form</p>
        <form id="contactform">
        <table id="formtable">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input class="input" id="name" type="text">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="label" for="email">E-mail Address</label>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input class="input" id="email" type="email">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="label" for="date">Date</label>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="datepicker" />
        </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input id="continue" type="button" class="submitbtn" value="Continue.." >

        </td>
        </tr>

        <div id="hideform">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="label" for="telephone">Telephone</label>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input class="input" id="telephone" type="text">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        <label class="label" for="location">Location</label>
        </td>

        <td>
        <input class="input" id="location" type="text">
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" >

        </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
        </table>
        </form> 

    </div>  

        <script>
        $("#submit").click(function () {
        $(".hide").show("slow");
        });    
        </script>
```

**CSS**

```
#form{
    float:left;
    background:#0b0b0b;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    width:29%;
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
}

#hideform{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: No elements have the class "hide"

Comment: wrap your code with `document.ready()` for initulising your functions.

Comment: @sdespont - that is correct. See my answer below :)

Comment: sorry I did make a class called hide to add to the chosen labels and input boxes, but that failed so I removed them but forgot to change the CSS property. Ive tried so many ways to hide half of the form using classes and Id's

Comment: I've updated my answer... should be exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an element `.hide` that does not exist in your HTML.

HTML for your form

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" >
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        $("#hideform").show("slow");
    });
});    
</script>
```

Alternatively you could modify your HTML from:

```
<div id="hideform">
```

To:

```
<div class="hide">
```

And Change the css from:

```
#hideform{display:none}
```

to

```
.hide{display:none}
```

Essentially I would look into how [jquery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) work so you have a better understanding of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a `div` that wraps part of your table – not good.
2. You do not have any element with the attribute `class="hide"` – jQuery will not find anything to [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Given you have defined not to show elements with the class 'hidden' via CSS, try something like this:

```
<div id="form">
  <h1>Booking</h1>
  <p>Fill in form</p>
  <form id="contactform">
    <table id="formtable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="input" id="name" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="label" for="email">E-mail Address</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="input" id="email" type="email" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="label" for="date">Date</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="input" type="text" id="datepicker" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <input id="continue" type="button" class="submitbtn" value="Continue.." >
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <label class="label" for="telephone">Telephone</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="input" id="telephone" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <label class="label" for="location">Location</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="input" id="location" type="text" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form> 
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactform').on('click', '#continue', function() {
      $('.hidden').show('slow');
    });
  });
</script>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fragmentedreality/Z2JQa/1/

Comment: Why would you want to show the element on click of the `#contactform` div? That makes no sense and is not what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should learn jQuery. The `$('#contactform').on('click', '#continue', function() {}));` fires only when the button is clicked. And it would even fire, if the button was placed there via javascript

Comment: @AdamD: fortunately the edit-history is public. You can take a look and see, that I did not change relevant (for your argumentation) parts. I added the `$(document).ready()`-part and changed the selector of the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)-delegate from `#show_hidden` to `#continue`, as I mistakenly added another button (`#show_hidden`), that was not visible, because it was lying in the hidden part of the form. Stop being so picky. SO is about helping and learning, not about accusing.
@JonathanLockley: consider marking it as answer, instead just commenting :-D